# Connect from C#.net to MySql database on host

Tags: mysql, .net, database, insert, host

I have a problem with connecting to MySQL database on my host from my C#.net.

```
server = "server ip";//localhost in php
        database = "database name";
        uid = "username";
        password = "password";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" +"DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        public void Insert()
        {
        string query = "INSERT INTO Orders (id,name,age) VALUES('1', 'nika', '28')";

        //open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

            //Execute command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //close connection
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }`
```

in my reference of MySQL.Data  in section "Copy Local" value is true.
So anyone can please tell me what to type in server string?

Answer (score 0):

localhost should work on a windows server.

What is your hosting environment? If you have a shared host, you may need to provide a different server name.

If your web server and database server are the same, localhost or 127.0.0.1 (local loopback) should work. If they're different you'll need to make sure you have network access between the two machines and have a proper DNS entry or IP address to put in 'server'.

Comment: Don't working i tried "localhost","server ip" "127.0.0.1" any other ideas?

Comment: What is your hosting environment? If you have a shared host, you may need to provide a different server name. "server ip" will never work. Whatever you put in the server part of the connection string needs to be a DNS-resolvable host. (IP address or fully-qualified domain name.

Comment: [link]http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL[/link]

i found this while searching but this thing not work for me any other ideas? i messaged to my web service support center

@Richthofen

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use another tool (i.e. SQLYog) to verify the connection to your MySQL server. This will help you resolve your issue.